# GSP Override Layout

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm using `Grails 2.4.3` and I want to overide the data attributes of the layout.

The layout `main.gsp`:

```
<body data-foo="bar">
```

The GSP that should override the Layout `bar.gsp`:

```
<body>
```

With that the HTML looks like the `main.gsp`, but i want that the body element has no attribute.

As this is only at one page i don't want to create a second layout.

How can I override the layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `jQuery` [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('body').attr('data-foo', 'foo');
    });
</script>
```